# @protocol extends @protocol

Tags: objective-c, protocols

can @protocol extend @protocol ?

```
@protocol Prot1 : Prot2
@end
```

like in java:

```
public interface Interface1 extends Interface2 {
}
```

Answer (score 25):

Yes, but with the syntax

```
@protocol Prot1 <Prot2, Prot3, Prot4> 
@end
```